# Finding duplicates on certain fields, excluding others (Oracle/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Vendor table that I am using to find duplicate entries.  An example of my data is below (fields of interest only).

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
| Vendor_No | Vendor_Name | Address | Bank_Acct_No |
+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
| 01        | First       | abc     | 123          |
| 01        | First       | abc     | 123          |
| 02        | Second      | def     | 456          |
| 03        | Second      | def     | 456          |
+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+
```

To look for duplicate values I would remove special characters from Vendor_Name, Address, and Bank_Acct_No.  Then I use the following:

```
select a.Vendor_No
     , a.Vendor_Name
     , a.Address
     , a.Bank_Acct_No
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No) as Dupe_Group1
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No) as Group1
from vendor_data a
```

If Dupe_Group1 is greater than 1 then it found a duplicate.  Then Group1 would have the same value for duplicate values.  It is a pretty decent system but in the example above I would want to exclude the first two rows being considered a duplicate because they have the same Vendor_No value.  The last two on the other hand would be considered duplicates.

Is there a way to take my code and exclude instances where  Vendor_No is the same yet keep it in my results (I need it to identify the vendors)?

---

Edit:

I would also run the same analysis for just duplicates on Bank_Acct_No (the results look the same for this example but with more data it would change that something could be a dupe in group2 but not group1).  Code would be:

```
select a.Vendor_No
     , a.Vendor_Name
     , a.Address
     , a.Bank_Acct_No
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No) as DupeGrp1
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No) as Grp1
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Bank_Acct_No) as DupeGrp2
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.Bank_Acct_No) as Grp2
from vendor_data a
```

Desired result set would be:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+------+----------+------+
| Vendor_No | Vendor_Name | Address | Bank_Acct_No | DupeGrp1 | Grp1 | DupeGrp2 | Grp2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+------+----------+------+
| 01        | First       | abc     | 123          | 1        | 1    | 1        | 1    |
| 01        | First       | abc     | 123          | 1        | 2    | 1        | 2    |
| 02        | Second      | def     | 456          | 2        | 3    | 2        | 3    |
| 03        | Second      | def     | 456          | 2        | 3    | 2        | 3    |
+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+------+----------+------+
```

Comment: I should have clarified a little better, I would have removed the "-" when running the duplicate analysis.  Sometimes people enter the same vendor with a different bank account number using a dash like in above so that is why there are two rows with the same vendor_no value.  I left out the part of the code where I remove that first just for simplicity.

Comment: How would you like your example _result_ table to look like?

Comment: I have added some more information including what I would want the result table to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have all these counts and ranks in the result set.  If you want to know if records are duplicates, but in a flag that says that.  Your logic is that two records are duplicates if they have the same `vendor_name`, `address`, and `bank_account_no` *and* they have different `vendor_no`.  So use this logic:

```
select a.Vendor_No, a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No,
       (case when min(Vendor_No) over (PARTITION BY a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No) <>
                  max(Vendor_No) over (PARTITION BY a.Vendor_Name, a.Address, a.Bank_Acct_No)
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as IsDup
from vendor_data a;
```

It turns out that comparing the `min()` and `max()` values is sufficient.  If there are two different values (assuming `NULL` is not being considered), then there are at least two rows.

Comment: Thanks, this works much better. I really need some better understanding of the analytic functions, I was definitely going about it with the brute strength and ignorance approach.